Issue with fetching all records using Spring Data JPA one to many mapping
I have a Transaction entity with a one-to-many relationship to Detail entities. When I try to fetch Transaction entities using a method that utilizes Spring Data JPA's Specification and Pageable, I'm only getting the Detail records that match the criteria, rather than all of them.
Here's how I'm fetching the Transaction entities:
@EntityGraph(value = "Transaction.details", attributePaths = ["details"])
fun findAll(search: Specification<Transaction>, pageable: Pageable): Page<Transaction>

And here's how I'm forming my Specification to filter based on Detail attributes:
val detailsJoin = root.get<Detail>("details")
predicates.add(builder.equal(detailsJoin.get<String>("invoiceId"), id))

My entity mappings are as follows:
Transaction Entity:
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "Transaction.details",
    attributeNodes = [NamedAttributeNode("details")]
)
@Table(name = "transaction_records")
@IdClass(TransactionId::class)
data class Transaction(
    @Id @Column(name = "part_id") var partId: Int,
    @Id @Column(name = "tx_id") var txId: String,
    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "transaction",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE]
    )
    var details: List<Detail> = ArrayList()
) : PersistableEntity<TransactionId>()

Detail Entity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "detail_records")
@IdClass(DetailId::class)
data class Detail(
    @Id @Column(name = "part_id") var partId: Int,
    @Id @Column(name = "detail_id") var detailId: String,
    @Id @Column(name = "tx_id") var txId: String,
    @Column(name = "invoice_id") var invoiceId: String,
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns(
        JoinColumn(
            name = "part_id",
            referencedColumnName = "part_id",
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false
        ),
        JoinColumn(
            name = "tx_id",
            referencedColumnName = "tx_id",
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false
        )
    )
    var transaction: Transaction? = null
) : PersistableEntity<DetailId>()

I expect to retrieve all Detail records associated with each Transaction, but I'm only getting the Detail records that match the criteria specified in my Specification. How can I modify my setup to ensure that all associated Detail records are fetched when querying Transaction entities?
